# Instascan single scans

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to do selective scans instead of contious scan. (probably doing it wrong ;-))

Thing is, I would like to start and stop the scanner based on selection of options..

```
console.log("Initiate Instascan");
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
  video: document.getElementById('preview'),
  continuous: true,
  mirror:false,
  refractoryPeriod: 5000,
  scanPeriod: 3,
  backgroundScan: false
});
Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
  var num_cams = cameras.length;
  if (num_cams > 0) {
     console.log('Get and Start Camera #'+cameras[cameraid]);
     scanner.start(cameras[cameraid]);
  } else {
    show_status('alert', 'No Cameras found! Select camera in Settings.');
    console.error('No cameras found. Select camera in Settings.');
  }
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
  console.log('Scanned Result:'+content);
});
```

Above works continously and scans QR after QR.

What I would like to work is:

```
console.log("Initiate Instascan");
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
  video: document.getElementById('preview'),
  continuous: false,
  mirror:false,
  backgroundScan: false
});
Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
  var num_cams = cameras.length;
  if (num_cams > 0) {
     console.log('Get and Start Camera #'+cameras[cameraid]);
     scanner.start(cameras[cameraid]);
  } else {
    show_status('alert', 'No Cameras found! Select camera in Settings.');
    console.error('No cameras found. Select camera in Settings.');
  }
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});

  $(document).on('click', '.asset_in_multiple_storage', function () {
    var assetid = $(this).data('prod-id');
    let content=scanner.scan();
    console.log('Scanned Result:'+content);
    var myArray = content.split("-");
    var data_string = myArray[1].split(" ");
    let first = myArray[0];
    let second = data_string[0];
    if (first == "L") {
      locationid = second;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '_save_asset_to_location.php',
      data: '&a='+assetid+'&l='+locationid+'&p=multiple',
      timeout: 2000,
      success: function(data) {
        show_status('info', 'Asset set to multiple locations');
    },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        show_status('alert', 'ERROR: Unable to run multiple locations script.');
      }
    });
  });
```

But here locationid is unknown (aka, content is unknown)

Anyone have an idea?

/Lars

Answer (score 0):

Went with https://github.com/mauntrelio/qrcode-reader - I could call the widget through jquery .on